# How to add a new property to a subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, properties, sub-array

I have an array with subarrays, I'm trying to add a new property `title` to each subarray. I have an implementation, but instead of adding the title to each subarray it puts it at the end of the array

```js
[
  { nextEpisodeDate: null },
  {
    episode: 12,
    id: '28800/tokyo-ghoul-12',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/12/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 11,
    id: '28459/tokyo-ghoul-11',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/11/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 10,
    id: '28001/tokyo-ghoul-10',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/10/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 9,
    id: '27741/tokyo-ghoul-9',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/9/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 8,
    id: '27092/tokyo-ghoul-8',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/8/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 7,
    id: '26689/tokyo-ghoul-7',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/7/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 6,
    id: '26529/tokyo-ghoul-6',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/6/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 5,
    id: '26431/tokyo-ghoul-5',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/5/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 4,
    id: '26373/tokyo-ghoul-4',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/4/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 3,
    id: '26278/tokyo-ghoul-3',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/3/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 2,
    id: '26188/tokyo-ghoul-2',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/2/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 1,
    id: '26103/tokyo-ghoul-1',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/1/th_3.jpg'
  }
]
```

***I want to achieve the following***

```js
  {
    episode: 12,
    title: '......'
    id: '28800/tokyo-ghoul-12',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/12/th_3.jpg'
  },
  {
    episode: 11,
    title: '......'
    id: '28459/tokyo-ghoul-11',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/11/th_3.jpg'
  },
```

***Implementation***

```js
 * @param  {Object} obj   The original object
 * @param  {String} key   The key for the item to add
 * @param  {Any}    value The value for the new key to add
 * @param  {Number} index The position in the object to add the new key/value pair [optional]
var addToObject = function (obj, key, value, index) {
    // Create a temp object and index variable
    var temp = {};
    var i = 0;
    // Loop through the original object
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // If the indexes match, add the new item
            if (i === index && key && value) {
                temp[key] = value;
            }
            // Add the current item in the loop to the temp obj
            temp[prop] = obj[prop];
            // Increase the count
            i++;
        }
    }
    // If no index, add to the end
    if (!index && key && value) {
        temp[key] = value;
    }
    return temp;
};

let list = addToObject(listByEps, 'title' , '....', 0)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `i === index` fails for every object except the first, which isn't an episode object. Also, that's an array of objects, not subarrays.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you'd like to give each element in the array (that has an episode) property another property called title?  And you'd like different title values in the different objects?  What is the source of the different title values?  It's super easy to add a prop to an object, even one in an array.  What's not understandable in this question is the source of title data, and how it relates to the existing objects

Comment: Hello, For each subarray I want to pass a new property called title, the problem I have is that it is not updating the values of the title property, it always shows me the same title.


You can see a temporary solution at the bottom. But it shows me the same title.

Answer (score 1):

by reference:

```
listByEps.forEach(item => item.title = '......')
```

pure assignment

```
let result = listByEps.map(item => {
  Object.assign({}, item, {title: '......'})
  return item;
});
```

just examples

Comment: It worked, but it's assigning the title property to {nextEpisodeDate: null, title: '.....'}, which it shouldn't.

It should only be the subarray that have the episode property.

Comment: He is assigning the same title for each sub-ray, and it shouldn't be that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really have another look at what it is exactly you're trying to achieve here, because it is a little bit confusing. For the purposes of this example I'm assuming that `listByEps` is the array that you posted in your first code section, since that seems to make the most sense for what you try to do next.

In which case the first thing to note is that `listByEps` is not an object, it is an array of objects. Trying to read the properties of it will not work as it has none, only indexed elements.

```
var addToObject = (array, key, value, index) => {
    if(index) {
        array[index][key] = value;
    } else {
        array.push({
            key: value
        })
    };
    return array;
}
```

This code targets the object at the given index in the `listByEps` array and adds the new key/value pair. If there is no index it pushes a new object to the end of the array. It then returns the whole array with the changes made, because that's what you seem to want it to do when you call it as `let list = addPropertyToObj(listByEps, 'title' , '....', 0)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**I have a temporary solution, but it is assigning the same title for all subarrays. It should assign different values in the title property. When I do console.log (title) it shows me all the titles**

```js
  let newListByEps;


    Array.from({length: chaptersTitles.length} , (v , k) =>{
      var title = chaptersTitles[k].title;
      console.log(title);

      // slice (1) to skip the subarray with the nextEpisodeDate property
      newListByEps =  listByEps.slice(1).map(item =>{
        Object.assign(item , {
          title: title
        })
        return item;
      })
    })

    console.log(newListByEps);
```

```js
[
  { nextEpisodeDate: null },
  {
    episode: 12,
    id: '28800/tokyo-ghoul-12',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/12/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 11,
    id: '28459/tokyo-ghoul-11',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/11/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 10,
    id: '28001/tokyo-ghoul-10',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/10/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 9,
    id: '27741/tokyo-ghoul-9',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/9/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 8,
    id: '27092/tokyo-ghoul-8',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/8/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 7,
    id: '26689/tokyo-ghoul-7',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/7/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 6,
    id: '26529/tokyo-ghoul-6',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/6/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 5,
    id: '26431/tokyo-ghoul-5',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/5/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 4,
    id: '26373/tokyo-ghoul-4',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/4/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 3,
    id: '26278/tokyo-ghoul-3',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/3/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 2,
    id: '26188/tokyo-ghoul-2',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/2/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  },
  {
    episode: 1,
    id: '26103/tokyo-ghoul-1',
    imagePreview: 'https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/1415/1/th_3.jpg',
    title: 'Ghoul'
  }
]
```

**The `chaptersTitles` variable has the list of titles and I want to pass it to the `newListByEps` variable. The reason that he is showing the same title for the whole newListByEps array is because every time he runs through the array he repeats the same list N times. In this case repeat the same arrat (chaptersTitles) 12 times**

**If someone can help me solve the problem I will appreciate it. Apparently the problem is in using `Array.from ({});`**

**This is the list of `chaptersTitles.`**

```js
[
  { episode: 1, title: 'Tragedy', date: '2014-07-04' },
  { episode: 2, title: 'Incubation', date: '2014-07-11' },
  { episode: 3, title: 'Dove', date: '2014-07-18' },
  { episode: 4, title: 'Supper', date: '2014-07-25' },
  { episode: 5, title: 'Scar', date: '2014-08-01' },
  { episode: 6, title: 'Cloudburst', date: '2014-08-08' },
  { episode: 7, title: 'Captivity', date: '2014-08-15' },
  { episode: 8, title: 'Circular', date: '2014-08-22' },
  { episode: 9, title: 'Birdcage', date: '2014-08-29' },
  { episode: 10, title: 'Aogiri', date: '2014-09-05' },
  { episode: 11, title: 'High Spirits', date: '2014-09-12' },
  { episode: 12, title: 'Ghoul', date: '2014-09-19' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

***The solution I had to use was based on merging two objects by manipulating the logic of the properties.***

```
const MergeRecursive = (obj1 , obj2) => {
  for(var p in obj2) {
    try{
      // Property in destination object set; update its value.
      if(obj2[p].constructor == Object){
        obj1[p] = MergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
      }else{
        obj1[p] = obj2[p];
      }
    }catch(e){
      // Property in destination object not set; create it and set its value.
      obj1[p] = obj2[p];
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}

module.exports = {
  MergeRecursive
}
```

```js
  listByEps =  MergeRecursive(listByEps.slice(1) , chaptersTitles)
```